# how to find the index of named node in a tregex pattern using stanford corenlp?

Tags: regex, stanford-nlp

How to find the index of the string matched by a named node in a given tregex pattern?
Here's an example of what I mean:

```
text="You can eat fruits such as apples and oranges."
tree="(ROOT (S (NP (PRP You)) (VP (MD can) (VP (VB eat) (NP (NP (NNS fruits)) (PP (JJ such) (IN as) (NP (NNS apples) (CC and) (NNS oranges)))))) (. .)))"
tregex="(JJ < such) $ (IN < as) $ (NP=examples)"
examples="(NP (NNS apples) (CC and) (NNS oranges))"
```

I would like to find the position of the named node `examples` in the original string `text`. Assuming I have an HTML for the `text`, I might `<span>` the named nodes as follows:

```
<div id="text">You can bring fruits such as <span class="eg">apples and oranges</span>.
```

Update1: The methods `leftCharEdge()` and `rightCharEdge()` do not work. It appears that they are off by number of spaces or "token separators". I took a look at the [source code](https://github.com/stanfordnlp/CoreNLP/blob/6d98bc6aa3f390eeeaa8659088445aad60d87ae1/src/edu/stanford/nlp/trees/Tree.java#L2655), and it appears that the *CharEdge* is calculated by adding the length of the *leaves*.

As per my observation:

```
Tree eg = matcher.getNode("examples");
int start = tree.leftCharEdge(eg);
int end = tree.rightCharEdge(eg);
System.out.println("start, end:" + start + "," + end);
//start, end: 21,37
```

Shouldn't the *spaces* be also taken into account? Offsetting the `start` and `end` with (approximately) the number of spaces before appears to solve the problem:

```
System.out.println("text[start,end]:" + text.substring(start+6, end+8));
//text[start,end]:apples and oranges
```

Number of words before `apples and oranges` = 6 = offset for start
Number of words within `apples and oranges` = 3 + offset for start - 1 = offset for end.

Answer (score 1):

If you're working from actual text (unlike your example where the variable `tree` is just a separate `String`), then character offsets will be embedded in the `CoreLabel` tokens in the `Tree`. See the example code below. (I'm adding a comment to say that the left/rightCharEdge methods aren't useful for this.)

```
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    LexicalizedParser parser = LexicalizedParser.getParserFromFile("edu/stanford/nlp/models/lexparser/englishPCFG.ser.gz", new Options());

    String[] texts = {"You can eat fruits such as apples and oranges.",
            "  You can  eat fruits   such as apples and   oranges .",
    };

    for (String text : texts) {
      Tree tree = parser.parse(text);

      List<CoreLabel> yield = tree.yield(new ArrayList<CoreLabel>());

      for (CoreLabel cl : yield) {
        System.out.printf("Word |%s| over char offsets [%d,%d)%n", cl.word(),
                cl.get(CoreAnnotations.CharacterOffsetBeginAnnotation.class),
                cl.get(CoreAnnotations.CharacterOffsetEndAnnotation.class));
      }
      System.out.println();
    }
  }
```